# Show that for any $E=E_1 \cup E_2$, $μ(E)=μ^∗(E_1)=μ^∗(E_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

The following is an exercise from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

> Let $E$ be a measurable set of positive Lebesgue measure. Show
> that E can be written as the disjoint union of two sets $E = E_1 ∪ E_2$
> so that $μ(E)=μ^∗(E_1)=μ^∗(E_2)$.

I have no idea how to construct a single example let alone proving for any measurable E. A useful hint also would be great, thanks!

Comment: @joshua, one is measure the other two are outer measures!

Comment: @L.G. Do you know about Bernstein sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F,G$ be two disjoint bernstein sets. Define $E_1:=E\cap F$, $E_2:=E-E_1\supseteq E\cap G$. We claim that the two sets satisfy the hypotesis. To see that, it suffices to show that $\mu^*(E\cap F)=\mu^*(E\cap G)=\mu(E)$, since then $\mu(E)\ge\mu^*(E_2)\ge \mu^*(E\cap G)=\mu(E)$ and so the equality must hold.
By simmetry, it suffices to prove the result for $F$. Its clear that $\mu^*(E\cap F)\le \mu(E)$, it remains to prove $\ge$: suppose that this is not true. Then there exists a covering of $E\cap F$ made of open sets (let us write the covering as $\cup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} A_i$), such that $\mu(E-\cup A_i)>0$. Since $E-\cup A_i$ has positive measure, it must contain a closed subset of positive measure $C$ which has to be uncountable. By definition of bernstein set, this implies $F\cap C\neq\emptyset$, a contradiction.

Comment: I have some questions: 1- What is $A$ (never introduced)? 2- Why a set of positive measure must contain a closed subset of positive measure which has to be uncountable? Thanks.

Comment: @L.G. 1- $A$ was a typo, it should have been $F$. 2- A set of positive measure must contain a closed subset of positive measure by inner regularity of the Lebesgue measure: $\mu(E)=\sup \{\mu(C):C\subset E; C=\bar C\}$. Since it has positive measure, it must be uncountable (a countable set has Lebesgue measure $0$)

Comment: Questions again! : 1- $(E-\cup A_i) \cap F = \emptyset$ and $C \subset E-\cup A_i$ how $F \cap C \ne  \emptyset$? 2- Even if $F\cap C\neq\emptyset$ how do you conclude a contradiction? (according to Wiki[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set] $F \cap C \ne  \emptyset$ must hold for every Bernstein $F$.)

Comment: @L.G. $F\cap C\neq\emptyset$ because $F$ is a Bernstein set and $C$ is an uncountable closed set. The contradiction is in the fact that $(F\cap E)$ and $E-\cup A_i$ are disjoint and yet $F$ intersects $C\subset E-\cup A_i$